# Read cookies sent by server when using POST request for login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, cookies, setcookie

I am doing a POST request for login,when logged in the server send a header "Set-Cookie" 
wich I have to get it and put it in the browser.I tryed all those methods none have worked

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    //$cookies['Set-Cookie']=response.headers('Set-Cookie');
    //console.log(headers);
    //console.log(headears()['Set-Cookie']);
    //console.log(headears(['Set-Cookie']));
    console.log(headers.getResponseHeaders()['Set-Cookie']);
});
```

The `console.log(headers);` print "succes" on the console and for the others I get "undefined" or "header is not a function".Can someone please help me.I tryed all the methods I saw in forums none have worked.Thank you.

I lately tryed using this  `console.log( $cookies.get('xxx'));` but the problem is that `$cookies.get()` works only when the cookies have already been stored in the browser.And I want to get them from the header in the printscreent and add them manually using `$cookies.put('myfav','oo');` Thank you.[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OQMM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the actual cookie that `Set-Cookie` creates.

Try

```
console.log( $cookies.get('CookieName'));
```

Also note that if it is an `httpOnly` cookie you won't have access to it. The same will be true for cross domain requests

Comment: `$cookies` is angular built-in service or external module dep?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly in earliest versions it was part of core but was moved to external module later on. Documentation is in main angular site though.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I tryed it but it doesnt work,how can I inject $cookie?I tryed this way  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngCookies"]) and in the controller both doesnt work.

Comment: Should be injecting `$cookies` not `$cookie` in controller https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies  Look at browser console errors

Comment: Yes I did the same shown on that page but its not working  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
        .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $cookie) those are the errors angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…0%20at%20Ac.c%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A4434%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)

Comment: That isn't `$cookies` with an `s` either